# No sound in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. Official troubleshooting does not work

Tags: sound, alsa

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS on a desktop with ASUS H110 motherboard. There is no sound when I plug headphones in the front audio jack. The HDMI audio and bluetooth speaker work fine. Window 10 also works fine with any method.

I've tried the [official troubleshooting](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure), but no luck.
When I ran

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2
sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2
killall pulseaudio
rm -r ~/.pulse*
ubuntu-support-status
sudo usermod -aG `cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami`
```

I got the error

```
Setting up linux-sound-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up alsa-base (1.0.25+dfsg-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up libasound2:amd64 (1.1.0-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up alsa-utils (1.1.0-0ubuntu5) ...
Setting up linux-image-4.10.0-30-generic
(4.10.0-30.34~16.04.1) ...
Running depmod.
update-initramfs: deferring update (hook will be called later)
Not updating initrd symbolic links since we are being     updated/reinstalled 
(4.10.0-30.34~16.04.1 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Not updating image symbolic links since we are being updated/reinstalled 
(4.10.0-30.34~16.04.1 was configured last, according to dpkg)
Examining /etc/kernel/postinst.d.
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.10.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-30-generic
run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.10.0-30-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.10.0-30-generic
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
Error!  The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which
does not match this kernel/arch.  This indicates that it should not be built.
```

And `bash alsa-info.sh --stdout` gave me the message `snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: ALC1150: SKU not ready 0x00000000`

I also tried editing `.asoundrc` as suggested by [JohnF](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/alt.os.linux.slackware/tJoTUTICINQ/hWYE6UV9zPsJ). None of these worked. I'm waiting for an update to solve this issue. Meanwhile, can anyone suggest a possible solution?

Update: I found the back audio jack works, which I've not noticed. However it is  strange that the front audio jack doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!
1st method
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshooting
Try everysingle step and let me know what's wrong
2nd method
Try taking them out and pluging them back in and select the default option that
shows on ubuntu then your headphones should work
3rd method
here's one that can help too!
[Upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10: Error! The dkms.conf for this module includes a BUILD_EXCLUSIVE directive which does not match this kernel/arch.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/626648/upgrading-from-14-04-to-14-10-error-the-dkms-conf-for-this-module-includes-a-b)
JoKeR's answer should help
4th method
try this one instead http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?t=300416
there are some answer's that can probally help you

Comment: Thanks for you suggestions. I followed method 1, Basic Troubleshooting Steps 1-6. `aplay` seems to be playing but I can't hear any sound. The sound module has been installed. In Step 7, I think my sound card hda-intel is supported. I tried unplug and plug, but no prompt showed up to let me choose the option. Method 3 does not apply since I have no un-configured modules. I can't open your link in Method 4.

Comment: your welcome glad to help :) right click the 4th method link and click open in new tab if your using firefox it should be loading just fine depends on your internet connection

Comment: Thanks again. The 4th method does not offer a working solution. I tried the two methods he mentioned but either works.